# Extending the ResultScriptWebPart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I have a requirement to handle search results before they are render back to the client. For example if a certain rule returns true, i need to remove the description field of the result (or just set it to empty string).

Since Post-Trimming search result only allow me to set true/false if to show the result its not suited for my needs.

Is there any event in the ResultScriptWebPart class that fires up once the results are returned and before rendering them back to the client? Is there a way to programmatically handle results before sending them back?